# nginx try_files not finding files in large directory (86k files)

Tags: linux, nginx, files, directory

To start out, the nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl_certificate     /example/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /example/privkey.pem;

    client_max_body_size 5M;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    location @example {
        add_header X-Orig-Url $uri;
        proxy_pass http://example; # the nodes
    }

    location ~ "^/assets/uploads/(.*)" {
        add_header X-Static-Asset $1 always;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        try_files /uploads/$1 @example;
    }

    location / {
        # Offline handling
        proxy_pass http://example;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Socket.io Support
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

And here's the directory structure

```
 /usr/share/nginx/html
   uploads
     system
       site-logo.png
       ~ 100 files
     _foo_bar
       site-logo.png
       ~ 86k files
```

The setup is an nginx server reverse proxying a Node.js express-powered server. Since Express is fairly slow at serving static assets, the `location ~ "^/assets/uploads/(.*)" {` is meant to intercept requests to upload assets and serve them directly from nginx instead.

The custom headers are just there for debugging purposes. Express adds an `X-Powered-By: express` header to requests it handles.

Here's where the weird stuff happens. I copied the file `site-logo.png` from `/usr/share/nginx/html/uploads/system` to `/usr/share/nginx/html/uploads/_foo_bar`. A request to `example.com/assets/uploads/system/site-logo.png` shows the `X-Static-Asset` header and not the `X-Powered-By: express` header. A request to `example.com/assets/uploads/_foo_bar/site-logo.png` instead shows the `X-Orig-Url` header and the `X-Powered-By: express` header, but not the `X-Static-Asset` header.

This tells me that all of the requests are being picked up by the location block, but nginx can't find the files in `_foo_bar` for some reason.

The directory at `/usr/share/nginx/html/uploads` is an NFS share, I'm not sure how relevant that is. My hypothesis is that nginx has trouble finding the file is such a large directory, but I'm not sure why that would be or how to fix it. I'm sure splitting the files into smaller directories would work, but I really don't want to do that because these file locations are already stored in the database in many different locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the nginx user owns the folders that you are serving from.

Comment: Or has execute permissions on the directories and read permissions on files in directory.